# Not able to connect docker container from remote(PING)

Tags: docker

Created Mongo db container on cloud and tested successfully ping from cloud to docker container.

But unable to ping docker container from the remote machine.
On the cloud firewall ICMP protocol is allowed for all IPV4 addresses. But still, ping is not working from remote machine to docker container.

Does this require any additional configuration in docker container?

Comment: Docker containers don't typically run processes that can accept ICMP ECHO packets; they use the higher-level TCP protocol instead.  Do you have a specific need to send ICMP packets to a container process, or would you normally use something like HTTP?  (What makes "ping" a first-class operation for you?)

Comment: I have an application running on remote host which will connect to db running on docker container  and the connection is not working . SO as part of debugging i was trying to PING to dcoker ip from remote host and its failing .